# Adding Google Analytics to website

Tags: iframe, widget, google-analytics

just wondering if it is possible to instead of using google analytics on google can you add the graphs to your own custom CMS panel instead of using the google service? Just like the iframe widgets you have with piwik? and if you can, can someone direct to where as i can find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does offer an [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) for retrieving data, but the catch is that the person going to your web page has to be able to login to GA to see the data.  There's no official way to write a script to authenticate and retrieve GA data to show to anonymous visitors.